# Google Gantt Chart Move X-axis on Top Instead of Bottom

Tags: javascript, charts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['gantt'] });
                              google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

```
                          function drawChart() {

                                         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                         data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
                                         data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
                                         data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
                                         data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
                                         data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
                                         data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
                                         data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
                                         data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

                                         data.addRows([
                                                        ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014            ', 'spring',
                                                                       new Date(2010, 5, 10), new Date(2010, 5, 12), null, 100, null],
                                                        ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
                                                                       new Date(2010, 5, 13), new Date(2010, 5, 14), null, 100, null],
                                                        ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
                                                                       new Date(2010, 5, 15), new Date(2010, 5, 16), null, 100, null],

                                         ]);
                                         debugger;
                                         var options = {
                                                        height: 400,
                                                        gantt: {
                                                                       palette: [
                                                                       ],
                                                                       trackHeight: 30,
                                                                       labelStyle: {
                                                                                      fontName: ["RobotoCondensedRegular"],
                                                                                      fontSize: 15
                                    `enter code here`                                   },
                                                                       textPosition: 'TOP',          ## Heading ##
                                                        },


                                         };

                                         var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                         for (i = 0; i < data.hg.length;i++) {
                                                        if (data.hg[i].c[2].v == 'spring') {
                                                                       options.gantt.palette.push({
                                                                                      "color": "#00FF00",
                                                                                      "dark": "#00FF00",
                                                                                      "light": "#00FF00"
                                                                       });
                                                        }
                                                        else if (data.hg[i].c[2].v == 'summer') {
                                                                       options.gantt.palette.push({
                                                                                      "color": "#00FF00",
                                                                                      "dark": "#0000FF",
                                                                                      "light": "#FF0000"
                                                                       });
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                                       options.gantt.palette.push({
                                                                                      "color": "#00FF00",
                                                                                      "dark": "#FF0000",
                                                                                                     "light": "#FF0000"
                                                                       });
                                                        }
                                         }
                                         chart.draw(data, options);
                          }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Above is the code of the google gantt charts that I am using and trying to acheive to move the bottom x-axis to the Top Side.

I beleive there is a little tweaking is needed by which I can do that Which I am unable to undestand. Any Help on this would be great.

Comment: there are limited [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#configuration-options) for the gantt chart. moving the x-axis to the top is not one. you could manually move the `<text>` elements, on the chart's `'ready'` event, by changing the `'y'` attribute. however, there is no room at the top to display them. so you would also have to move every other chart element down... -- maybe check out [dhtmlxGantt](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt)

Comment: I have edited my question with some code snippets, may be that would help to resolve this